# Run different function on clicking again

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, jquery-1.7

I have this code

```
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '100%'});
});
```

Works fine for once. But I want to bring back **div2** on clicking again.
toggle would've worked but the problem is, I don't want to hide div2 but just lower its width with animation.

What would be the correct code to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated solution

Since `.toggle` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9, the go-to solution would now involve manually keeping track of clicks in order to decide what to do. A generalized drop-in replacement for toggle would be:

```
var handlers = [
    // on first click:
    function() {
        jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '50%'});
    },
    // on second click:
    function() {
        jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '100%'});
    }
    // ...as many more as you want here
];

var counter = 0;
$(".button").click(function() {
    // call the appropriate function preserving this and any arguments
    handlers[counter++].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
    // "wrap around" when all handlers have been called
    counter %= handlers.length;
});
```

#### Original answer

You can simply use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
jQuery('.button').toggle(function() {
    jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '50%'});
}, function() {
    jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '100%'});
});
```

On each click, this will toggle the visibility of `.div1` completely and toggle the width of `.div2` between 50% and 100%.

If you don't want to show `.div1` again after first hiding it, simply do

```
jQuery('.button').toggle(function() {
    jQuery('.div1').animate({width: 'hide'});
    jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '50%'});
}, function() {
    jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '100%'});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep a flag outside of the method:

```
var open = false;

jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    open = !open;

    if(open) {
        jQuery('.div1').animate({width: '100%'});
        jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '100%'});
    } else {
        jQuery('.div1').animate({width: '0%'});
        jQuery('.div2').animate({width: '50%'}); // Or whatever else you want to lower it to
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a toggleClass instead and using css to handle the different styles.

Answer (score -1):

Use variable and update it after each click, example:

```
`
var $toggle = 0;
$('.button').click(function(){
    if($toggle == 0){
        $('.div1').animate({width: '50%'});
        $toggle = 1;
    }else{
        $('.div1').animate({width: '100%'});
        $toggle = 0;
    };

});
`
```

Comment: Oh hey, it’s my answer from 2012.